# SSJS Script not Looping Through

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have some code which doesn't seem to loop through the i variable incrementally... any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");

var DE1 = DataExtension.Init("abc-123-def-456");
var MaxIt = DE1.Rows.Retrieve();

for (var i = 0; i < MaxIt.length; i++)
        {

        var IT = Platform.Function.Lookup('SSJS_Query_updating_01','QueryExternalKey','Row',[i]);
        var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(IT);
        var QT1 = "SELECT MR.* FROM masterDE MR ";
        var QT2 = "WHERE 1 + 1 = "
        var QT3 = [i];

        var status = qd.Update({
                                QueryText: QT1 + QT2 + QT3
                                });

        status.Perform()
        }
```

the MaxIT DE has two rows with, so i expect this to loop through both rows picking up the ext key for the two queries and re-writing both exactly the same as above. I suspect that i am not using the [i] iteration correctly but not sure

UPDATE

I have tweaked the code and simplified what I am asking but i can only get one of the two queries in the data extension to update and it's always the second row of the two rows in the data extension. Anything in this code that stands out as to why both query definitions sitting in the fields won't update?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");

    var DE1 = DataExtension.Init("abc-123-def-456");
    var MaxIt = DE1.Rows.Retrieve();

    for (var i = 1; i = MaxIt.length; i++)
        {

    var IT = Platform.Function.Lookup('SSJS_Query_updating_01','QueryExternalKey','Row', [i] + 1);
    var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(IT);
    var QT1 = "SELECT M.* ";
    var QT2 = "FROM [masterDE] M";

    var status = qd.Update({
                            QueryText: QT1 + QT2
                            });

    status.Perform();
    }

</script>
```

Note i've added i + 1... i can't get it to update even one query without putting the +1 there

Comment: is it supposed to be `WHERE 1 + 1 = [0]` or `1+1 = 0` for first iteration? What is the purpose of the brackets you have there?

Comment: Its a great help to me to put the code in a cloud page and add Write statements throughout the code as debug. If you just want the value of i, I think you have to remove the brackets.

Comment: @Gortonington, I was just adding SQL query code that would concatenate together. I need to do something more complicated than the above but i am taking baby steps as I am new to this and maybe the steps will help others when searching. I just need the loop to work and my goal here is to update the two query references i have in my data extension with the SQL query text

Comment: @SebOB, thanks i will try the bracket removal. I am so new to SSJS and indeed JavaScript itself, so not sure how to do a Write statement!

Comment: Just put the code in a cloud page and add Write('some text<br>'); and press Preview, you will see the text written in the page. You can put variables as well so you can follow the code.

Comment: The brackets in ssjs make it into an array which is why it's not outputting anything. Just `QT3 = i;` should do it

Comment: i have removed the square brackets but still not getting the updates to the SQL queries when running this

Comment: @Gortonington any ideas at all? i'm completely stumped as to how to get the updated script to run through the two query definitions and update them

Comment: I believe the issue is the brackets around the i (`[i]`) try to change it to `i + 1` instead. The brackets would declare the 'i' to be an array.

Comment: it hasn't worked... Do you think my data extension needs some specific formatting for the fields i use? The Row field is formatted as number and since it is picking up Row 2, Why do i need the +1? I thought having an i there would loop through the code with the {} area. so i = 1 first (loop through as 1) then increment i up by 1, so i = 2 (loop through as 2) then since the rows of the DE are only 2 the i cannot go any higher and the loop {} ends. However, like i said in the question, if i don't have the +1 there it doesn't work for Row 2 neither (which it currently works for)

Comment: OH DUH. ok, the issue in your new loop are that you are using `i=1` in your for loop AND that you have it so it will only run the loop when it is equal to the max length (`i = MaxIt.length`). Javascript starts with row 1 as '0' instead of at '1' like AMPscript and you need to change your loop break to include all below the max length. You will need to change the loop to `for (var i = 0; i < MaxIt.length; i++) ` like you had in your original

Comment: thanks @Gortonington, i have changed the loop break and removed the square brackets... this now runs and updates the Row 1 query but doesn't do Row 2! Could this be the field the Lookup is looking at - the Row field is formatted as Number and each record of the DE has a number - The first being 1 and the second 2. I am assuming the retrieve that I'm doing and the length of it is equal to 2 given that the DE has two rows/records

Comment: removing the `status.Perform();` carries out the task correctly looping through the ext keys on the DE. Happy for someone else to write this up (and the remove square brackets, correct loop break code) as the answer but will give it a day or two and answer this one if not

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");

var DE1 = DataExtension.Init("abc-123-def-456");
var MaxIt = DE1.Rows.Retrieve();

for (var i = 0; i < MaxIt.length; i++)
        {

        var IT = Platform.Function.Lookup('SSJS_Query_updating_01','QueryExternalKey','Row', i + 1);
        var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(IT);
        var QT1 = "SELECT M.* ";
        var QT2 = "FROM [masterDE] M";

        var status = qd.Update({
                                QueryText: QT1 + QT2
                                });


        }
```

so i cannot be in the [brackets], i should be less than maxit.length and finally the `status.perform` has to be removed, `qd.Update` performs the task